# Adjust row height and cell text - Latex

Tags: tables, cell, nicematrix

I'm trying to create table in `Latex` like this;

```
\begin{table}[h|]
  \begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  
      & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large Actual Values} \\
      & & Positive (1) & Negative (0) \\\cline{3-4}
      {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large Values}} & Positive (1) & 
      \multicolumn{1}{|l|} {TP} & \multicolumn{1}{l|} {FP} \\\cline{3-4}  
      {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\large Predicted    }} &  Negative (0) &  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}  {FN}  &  \multicolumn{1}{l|} {TN}  \\\cline{3-4}
    
    \end{tabular}

  \end{center}
  \caption[Confusion Matrix]{\small Confusion Matrix}
  \label{table: matrix}
\end{table}
```

But it ends up like this;

[image: Matrix Image]

I've two queries here.

> How can I center align cell text?

I tried different methods but due to `multicolumn`, it is not adjusting cell text in center.

> How can I adjust height of both rows same?

I seriously have no idea how can I do this?

I'm new to latex, so any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Doe "center align"  refer to horizontally or vertically centere text or both?

Comment: where to put this "center align"?

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my previous comment. I just wanted to know what your requirement "How can I center align cell text?"  refers to. Do you want to horizontally or vertically center the contents in your cells or do you want both?

Comment: You have not provided a usable test file but if I guess a preamble I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`|'.`

Comment: @leandriis I want both

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience @DavidCarlisle I actually don't know how can I share usable test file?

Comment: simply edit the code block above so it starts `\documentclass{article}` and ends `\end{document}` and demonstrates the problem without generating errors.

Comment: you specified centred columns then used `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}` the only purpose of which is to over-ride the `c` with `l` for left alignment. Is the answer just "delete` the multicolumn or was there some other intention for those commands?

Comment: o yes my bad, that was just a copy/paste issue.. Thank you...

Comment: How can I adjust height of rows??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nicematrix` package provides the command  `\Block` which takes care of vertical and horizontal centering (neither `multicolumn` nor `multirow` are needed).

It also allows global directives to expand the cells. The code obtained is very simple and easy to maintain.

You need to compile it twice the first time. Later only once,  if you do not change the setup of the table.

[image: x]

**UPDATE** nicematrix v6.24

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering              
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c@{\enskip}c@{\enskip}wc{2.5cm}wc{2.5cm}}
                &               & \Block{1-2}{\large Actual Values}         \\[1ex]   
                &               & \Block{}{Positive (1)}    & Negative (0)  \\[1ex]
                \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\rule[-1.1cm]{0pt}{2.5cm}}% make the cells a square
                \Block{2-1}<\rotate\large >{Predicted Values}
                & Positive (1)  & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{}TP  & FP    \\
                & Negative (0)  & FN                        & Tn    \\         
        \end{NiceTabular}
        \medskip
        \caption[Confusion Matrix]{\small Confusion Matrix}
        \label{table: matrix}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```